# jQuery On() from another handler

Tags: jquery, selector

I have this jS Fiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/E7MSN/101/

If you click inside the textbox and press return then you get a set of options and you can use the up and down arrows to navigate throught the items.

If you click the ADD link then try to navigate you can only navigate through the static - pre-defined ones.  Can you assist me in finding a way around this?

Thanks

Full Code Below

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="autofill"/>
    <a href='#' class='add'>ADD</a>
 <div class="services">
<div class="items">
    <ul>                           
        <li class="mail-icon selected"><a href="#" id="mail">mail</a></li>
        <li class="forum-icon"><a href="#" id="forum">lang</a></li>
        <li class="chat-icon"><a href="#" id="chat">chat</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

 $(".add").click(function(){
      $(".items").append("<li>Item</li>");
 });

 });


 $("#autofill").keydown(function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 13) { // enter
         if ($(".services").is(":visible")) {
             selectOption();
         } else {
             $(".services").show();
         }
         menuOpen = !menuOpen;
     }
     if (e.keyCode == 38) { // up
         var selected = $(".selected");
         $(".services li").removeClass("selected");
         if (selected.prev().length == 0) {
             selected.parent().children().last().addClass("selected");
         } else {
             selected.prev().addClass("selected");
         }
     }
     if (e.keyCode == 40) { // down
         var selected = $(".selected");
         $(".services li").removeClass("selected");
         if (selected.next().length == 0) {
             selected.parent().children().first().addClass("selected");
         } else {
             selected.next().addClass("selected");
         }
     }
 });

 $(".services li").mouseover(function() {
     $(".services li").removeClass("selected");
     $(this).addClass("selected");
 }).click(function() {
     selectOption();
}); 

function selectOption() {
    $("#autofill").val($(".selected a").text());
    $(".services").hide();
}
```

Comment: This question would be much better if you included *the relevant* code in the post as well. Questions and answers on Stack Overflow should not need to rely entirely on stuff elsewhere.

Comment: This type of question requires a "live demo" for detail hence the inclusion of the jsFiddle which includes all the code.

Comment: Yes, but your question becomes useless for everyone else who have similar problems. I think [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73899/188419) post on Meta sums it up pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
$(".services li").mouseover(function ... )
```

With

```
$('.services').on('mouseover', 'li', function... )
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but this does not fix the up and down arrow issue.  This does solve the hover issue however

Answer (score 1):

You are appending the `li` after the `ul`, replace...

```
$(".items").append("<li>Item</li>");
```

With

```
$(".items ul").append("<li>Item</li>");
```